# How to convert one generic list to another in java

Tags: java, generics, enums, type-conversion

I am trying to convert one generic list of enums to another generic list type but always getting the following compile error:

> Is not applicable for the arguments

```
private static <T extends Enum<T>> List<T> enumListFromEnumList(List<Object> sourceEnumsList, Class<T> classObject) {
        List<T> enums = new ArrayList<T>();

        if(sourceEnumsList != null) {
            for(Object enumObject : sourceEnumsList) {
                if (enumObject instanceof Enum)
                    enums.add(Enum.valueOf(classObject, enumObject.toString().toUpperCase()));
            }
        }

        return enums;
    }
```

Even I tried this:

```
private static <T extends Enum<T>> List<T> enumListFromEnumList(List<T> sourceEnumsList, Class<T> classObject) {
        List<T> enums = new ArrayList<T>();

        if(sourceEnumsList != null) {
            for(T enumObject : sourceEnumsList) {
                enums.add(Enum.valueOf(classObject, enumObject.toString().toUpperCase()));
            }
        }

        return enums;
    }
```

This is how I'm consuming the function:

```
adapterInfo.setResponseTypeList( enumListFromEnumList(info.getResponseTypeList(), CAPInfo.ResponseType.class));
```

**Updates:**

It works when I convert to this:

```
private static <S extends Enum<S>, T> List<S> enumListFromEnumList(List<T> sourceEnumsList, Class<S> classObject) {
        List<S> enums = new ArrayList<S>();

        if(sourceEnumsList != null) {
            for(T enumObject : sourceEnumsList) {
                enums.add(Enum.valueOf(classObject, enumObject.toString().toUpperCase()));
            }
        }

        return enums;
    }
```

So now the question is how to translate "`<S extends Enum<S>, T> List<S>`" part ( I mean how it works)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do something simple with a complicated method. Can you describe what you've got and what you're trying to achieve, so people can suggest the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Also, when working with enums, you usually want to use EnumSet, not a List (unless you require duplicate values or a custom order)

Comment: Thank you for improving it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for (I think) :

```
enum EnumA {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD
}

enum EnumB {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD
}

private static <A extends Enum<A>, B extends Enum<B>> List<B> enumListFromEnumList(List<A> sourceEnumsList, Class<B> classObject) {
    List<B> enums = new ArrayList<B>();

    if (sourceEnumsList != null) {
        for (A enumObject : sourceEnumsList) {
            enums.add(Enum.valueOf(classObject, enumObject.toString().toUpperCase()));
        }
    }

    return enums;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<EnumA> listA = new ArrayList<EnumA>();
    listA.add(EnumA.FIRST);
    listA.add(EnumA.THIRD);
    List<EnumB> listB = enumListFromEnumList(listA, EnumB.class);
    System.out.println(listB);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the meaning of <S extends Enum<S>, T> List<S> or <A extends Enum<A>, B extends Enum<B>> . Sorry new to generics

Comment: "<A extends Enum<A>, B extends Enum<B>>" : This is the part where you 'declare' the generics you are about to use in the method, and where you apply constraints on them. Here, you need 2 generics, both inheriting of the Enum class. This is a bit complicated to explain in a comment why a enum inheritance is constructed like this, have a look on google eventually. "List<B>" : this is the return type.